What’s Wrong with my Code? "PHP ERROR: Uncaught ArgumentCountError"
I have seen that there are already some articles on this topic, but unfortunately I have not found a solution for my code.
I’m exporting orders from Woocommerce with custom codes (plugin WP ALL IMPORT) as an XLM file, which has worked very well so far with the PHP code snippets I use.
Now I get this PHP ERROR while exporting.
PHP Error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function
PHP Error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function my_get_order_items(), 0 passed in /www/htdocs/w01c48e0/web/wp-content/plugins/wp-all-export-pro/libraries/WpaeXmlProcessor.php(528) : eval()'d code on line 1 and exactly 1 expected on line 3 of the Functions Editor

MY XML CODE
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>
    <!-- BEGIN LOOP -->
        <commission>{Bestell ID}</commission>
        <production>1</production>

        <receiver>
            <line1>{Shipping First Name} {Shipping Last Name}</line1>
            <line2>{Shipping Company}</line2>
            <street>{Shipping Address 1}</street>
            <streetnumber>{Shipping Address 2}</streetnumber>
            <country_code>{Shipping Country}</country_code>
            <zip>{Shipping Postcode}</zip>
            <city>{Shipping City}</city>
            <email>{Customer Account Email Address}</email>

        </receiver> 

        <items> 
            [my_get_order_items({Bestell ID})]
        </items>
    <!-- END LOOP -->
</order>

MY PHP CODE
<?php

function my_get_order_items( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( absint($order_id) ); // Get the WC_Order object
    
    if ( ! is_a($order, 'WC_Order') ) {
        return false; // Exit if not an order
    }
    $order_details = ""; // Initialize variable as string to store order details

    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        if ( ! ( strpos($item->get_name(), 'KERAMIKTASSE') !== false
        || strpos($item->get_name(), 'BAUMWOLLTASCHE') !== false
        || strpos($item->get_name(), 'SWEATSHIRT') !== false
        || strpos($item->get_name(), 'HOODIE') !== false
        || strpos($item->get_name(), 'T-SHIRT') !== false ) ) { 
            continue; 
        }
        $product    = $item->get_product(); // Get the product object
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // Get the product ID

        $order_details .= "**LT**item**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**ID**GT**" . $product->get_sku() . "**LT**/ID**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**produktname**GT**" . $item->get_name() . "**LT**/produktname**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**amount**GT**" . $item->get_quantity() . "**LT**/amount**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**upload**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'upload', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/upload**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**size**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'size', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/size**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**groesse**GT**" . $product->get_attribute('pa_groesse')  . "**LT**/groesse**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**material**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'material', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/material**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**print**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'print', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/print**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**variante**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'variante', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/variante**GT**";
        $order_details .= "**LT**category**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'category', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/category**GT**";

 //add options to the output
        $order_details .= "**LT**Options**GT**";
        if(get_field( 'groupid_115', $product_id )) {             
        $order_details .= "**LT**Option**GT****LT**ID**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'groupid_115', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/ID**GT****LT**Value**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'value_115', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/Value**GT****LT**/Option**GT**"; }
        
        if(get_field( 'groupid_117', $product_id )) {             
            $order_details .= "**LT**Option**GT****LT**ID**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'groupid_117', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/ID**GT****LT**Value**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'value_117', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/Value**GT****LT**/Option**GT**"; }
        
        if(get_field( 'groupid_118', $product_id )) {             
            $order_details .= "**LT**Option**GT****LT**ID**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'groupid_118', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/ID**GT****LT**Value**GT**" . maybe_serialize( get_field( 'value_118', $product_id ) ) . "**LT**/Value**GT****LT**/Option**GT**"; }
        
    }
    
    return $order_details;
}

?>

I haven't changed anything in the code or in the plugin settings. My host switched to PHP 8.0 yesterday (previously PHP 7.2).
Is the error message related to this? And what do I have to change in the code to make it work again?

The change that should be relevant to this, happened between 7.0 and 7.1 already, https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php Before this used to only create a warning, but from 7.1, it should have thrown an error exception.

[my_get_order_items({Bestell ID})] - could either be that this is accessing the wrong field / element to begin with (so that no order ID gets passed in for any of your orders), or perhaps this isn't set for some orders in your input data. Giving the function parameter a default value, function my_get_order_items( $order_id = 0), should fix the error (you should also make it return false then, when the passed order id is 0 - probably best before it even tries to call wc_get_order) - but whether the result will make sense then, you'd have to check.

If you read the error message carefully, you see that my_get_order_items() is not called with the expected (one) argument. As the template calls [my_get_order_items({Bestell ID})] I would say, that Bestell ID is not set before calling. Make sure it is exactly written the same (upper/lower case and spaces). Please edit the question and add the code part where you hydrate the template.

@MarkusZeller Thank you for your ideas.
I'll check the spelling again. The strange thing is that it still worked with this code until yesterday....

@MarkusZeller Thank you for your advice.
I have discovered that unfortunately the “automatic translation” of the plugin (English -> German) no longer works.
Therefore the name “Bestell ID” is no longer available and is now called “Order ID”. If I adjust this, everything works again.
Problem solved...
